# Elasticsearch can't start

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, apache-servicemix

I use ServiceMix in the developments and I have bundle that depend ElasticSearch (usually ES customers).

I have my bundle that depend ElasticSearch that are "Failed" and I found that the problem is Elasticseach.

I tried to put a new ES, change version ... but still nothing works.

Here logs when I do ./elasticsearch :

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /ke/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.0/logs/elasticsearch.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:131)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:216)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [file].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /ke/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.0/logs/elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:131)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:216)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [index_indexing_slow_log_file].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /ke/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.0/logs/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupLogging(Bootstrap.java:131)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:216)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [index_search_slow_log_file].
[2016-04-15 15:53:49,386][INFO ][node                     ] [Mogul of the Mystic Mountain] version[1.7.0], pid[29511], build[929b973/2015-07-16T14:31:07Z]
[2016-04-15 15:53:49,388][INFO ][node                     ] [Mogul of the Mystic Mountain] initializing ...
[2016-04-15 15:53:49,499][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Mogul of the Mystic Mountain] loaded [], sites []
{1.7.0}: Initialization Failed ...
- ElasticsearchIllegalStateException[Failed to created node environment]
        AccessDeniedException[/ke/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.7.0/data]
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the value of `path.logs` you have in your `elasticsearch.yml` file?

Comment: Looks like there's an access issue too.

Comment: i change access to root and I have another log now. But elasticsearch don't run again , I post the log in answer

Comment: My path.logs :  /path/to/logs

Answer (score -1):

when I run ./elasticsearch with root

```
[2016-04-15 16:11:38,741][INFO ][node                     ] [Ghost Rider 2099] started
    [2016-04-15 16:11:41,912][WARN ][cluster.service          ] [Ghost Rider 2099] failed to connect to node [[Stygyro][hy3R6zedSC-gbc4piorOrw][cmaze-VMMaze.vm.vdi.s1.p.fti.net][inet[/10.107.1.100:9301]]]
    org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Stygyro][inet[/10.107.1.100:9301]] connect_timeout[30s]
            at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:825)
            at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:758)
            at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:731)
            at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:216)
            at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:460)
            at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:188)
            at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:158)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.107.1.100:9301
            at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:139)
            at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83)
            at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
            at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
            at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            ... 3 more
```